# Not working variables in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi i have 3 triggers i can not compile, I would appriciate some help as i cant get around it.
1) I have this table in PL/SQL - **Solution was the first comment under this post!**

```
CREATE TABLE Personel_Project (
    ProjectID INT,
    PersonID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (ProjectID) REFERENCES Project(ProjectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Personel(PersonID)
);/
```

And this trigger wont work, im almost sure it has something to do with the name declaration.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER peopleInProjects 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Personel_Project 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
projectnumber NUMBER := :new.ProjectID;
peoplecount NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    Select INTO peoplecount Count(PersonID) FROM Personel_Project Group by projectnumber;
    dbms_output.put_line('ID of project: ' || projectnumber); 
    dbms_output.put_line('number of people working in this project: ' || peoplecount); 
END; 
/
```

Im getting this error
Error(4,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

The idea behind this trigger is for it to start up when somebody edits this table in DB, and we can see how many people are working in this project we have just edited.

2)

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
    ProjectID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Due_date DATE,
    Cost INT,
    Payout INT
);
```

With this table i was getting an error when i was trying to call the change in table by :new.DUE_DATE and now im with :DUE_DATE. Unable to move forward

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER showChange
  BEFORE
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE OF DUE_DATE, COST, PAYOUT OR
    DELETE
  ON PROJECT
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('you put in this information' || :DUE_DATE || :COST || :PAYOUT );
    WHEN UPDATING('Due_date') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('you updated due date to be' || :DUE_DATE );
    WHEN UPDATING('Cost') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('you updated cost to be' || :COST );
    WHEN UPDATING('Payout') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('you updated Payout to be' || :PAYOUT );
    WHEN DELETING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You deleted the project');
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

I would really appriciate all the help i can get. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like just a syntax error. `Select Count(PersonID) INTO peoplecount`.

Comment: ok, that works for number 1 :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER peopleInProjects 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Personel_Project 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
projectnumber NUMBER := :new.ProjectID;
peoplecount NUMBER;
BEGIN 
    Select INTO peoplecount Count(PersonID) FROM Personel_Project Group by projectnumber;
    dbms_output.put_line('ID of project: ' || projectnumber); 
    dbms_output.put_line('number of people working in this project: ' || peoplecount); 
END; 
/
```

The `Select INTO peoplecount Count(PersonID) FROM...` That is not how you do a `select <column1>, <column2>, ... INTO <variable1>, <variable2>, ...`

[Oracle DB SELECT INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345)